# How to exclude a list of results from mysql query

Tags: mysql, matching

Lets say I want to select all rows that does not contain a long list of words. Lets say this list is shortened for the sake of this example to only "example1" and "example2".

Im guessing using REGEXP would be the best option, instead of specifying

> and field not like '%example1%' and field not like '%example2%'

but Im not sure how to go about it.
Im guessing something like this?

```
WHERE !REGEXP(field, '/example1|example2/')
```

Comment: How many examples would you have ? Maybe you could assign a type which is an INT to each example so you could do a NOT IN (1,2,3) etc not 100% sure if that is correct but just a quick idea.

Comment: the list will be maybe 50 items long, so im just looking for a way to make it looke a bit cleaner then typing 50 rows of 'and field not like'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use LOCATE:

```
set @string = '/example1|example2/';
select * from YourTable
where locate(YourStringField,@String) = 0
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d075/3

Comment: this solution will not check for substrings, eg. if your column contains `word1 example1` it will be returned: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c7da/3

Comment: Does your solution check for substrings? When I clicked your sqlfiddle link, it appears all the results were returned.

In order to search for substrings, I think it would be helpful to have the exclusions in a table, left join with `Like`, and then force a null in the where clause: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92ec69/2

Comment: yes, my solution checks for substrings, if you click my link you will see both your query and my query .. of course if values are more than just a few, it's better to use a left join

Answer (score 1):

MySQL support for regular expressions is very limited, but I think you could use this solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  field NOT RLIKE '[[:<:]]example1[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]example2[[:>:]]'
```

where `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are word boundaries, and | is the OR operator